# How to validate regular expresion working wrong

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, plist

I'm writing a regular expression for a syntax highlight `vscode` extension and is not working as desired. The regular expression is in a `plist` file and is the following:

```
<string>(\@[\p{L}_]+[\w]*)</string>
```

I supposed that this expression will find `@variable`.

My problem is that is just finding the following: `@@variable`.
So it just find the string I want when it is preceded by an `@` character. Why is happening that?

[image]

When I write the expression:

```
<string>(\#[\p{L}_]+[\w]*)</string>
```

I supposed that this expression will find `#key`. That expression works correctly.

Furthermore, if I use this tool https://regexr.com/ to test regular expresions it is working fine. So what is the problem with vs code? It is something about the expresion flags maybe?

[image]

Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: This does not make much sense. The `(\@[\p{L}_]+[\w]*)` regex matches `@`, 1+ letters or `_` and the any 0 or more word chars. Thus, it can match `@variable`, not `@@variable`. If the match is not anchored, it can match `@variable` inside `@@variable`. How can we repro the issue?

Comment: How can I fix the problem then? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: How can I anchor the expresion?

Comment: So, I was right: it is not `@@var` that is found, but `@var` inside `@@var`. So, what is your requirement? Match the pattern when found in between whitespaces or start/end of string? Try `(?<!\S)(@[\p{L}_]\w*)(?!\S)`

Answer (score -1):

The regular expresion is correct. The problem was that I was writing a vs code extension and I had to put this line in an upper position of the file because there was another regular expresion interfering. 
Thank you! @WiktorStribiżew